# How can I remove all elements from a vector that matches a pattern?

Tags: r, subset, grepl

```
ncvars = c("prate", "arate", "wpd", "Atm1", "Atm2", "area", "fC", "bas__1", "bas__asssaa", "bas__Clow", "bas__g2333e", "baser__arge", "bas__Aow", "bas__Aass")
```

Now, I want to remove all elements that are

- exactly the name `area`
- matches this string `bas__`

How can I do this?

---

Trial

```
patterns <- c("bas__", "area")
ncvars %>%
  filter(.,grepl(paste(patterns, collapse="|")))
```

Comment: Added...........

Comment: can you dput your data?

Comment: Dovetailing on @Hardikgupta's comment. It's more likely that we will be able to help you if you provide a [complete minimal reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to go along with your question. Something we can _easily_ work from and use to show you how it might be possible to answer your question. I realize you got an answer already, but your question and a potential answer becomes much more useful for others if there's  a [complete minimal reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can just negate `grepl` with `!` and also to match exactly, you need `^..$` anchors to match the start(`^`) and end(`$`) of string:

```
ncvars[!grepl('^area$|bas__', ncvars)]
```

---

```
ncvars
# [1] "prate"       "arate"       "wpd"         "Atm1"        "Atm2"        "area"        "fC"          "bas__1"     
# [9] "bas__asssaa" "bas__Clow"   "bas__g2333e" "baser__arge" "bas__Aow"    "bas__Aass"  
ncvars[!grepl('^area$|bas__', ncvars)]
# [1] "prate"       "arate"       "wpd"         "Atm1"        "Atm2"        "fC"          "baser__arge"
```

Comment: What does ^ and $ surrounding area signify? Thanks.

Comment: They match the beginning and end of a string. So `^area$` matches `area` exactly instead of as a substring.

Comment: Ah. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 4):

A `tidyverse` solution:

```
library(stringr)
stringr::str_subset(ncvars, pattern = "^area$|^bas__", negate = TRUE)
[1] "prate"       "arate"       "wpd"         "Atm1"        "Atm2"        "fC"          "baser__arge"
```

Comment: This solution did not remove the element - it only blanked it out

Comment: @ArthurYip: answer has been updated based on vlad1490's suggested improvement, which removes the wanted elements.